# How to make a StalemateException

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game and I need to figure how to do a StalemateException.

This is my GUI code:

```
package Game;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import exceptions.StalemateException;


public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6, tf7,
tf8, tf9;
JFrame frame;

gameLogic game = new gameLogic();
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GUI myProg = new GUI();
}

public GUI() throws StalemateException{


    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    tf1 = new JTextField("");
    tf2 = new JTextField("");
    tf3 = new JTextField("");
    tf4 = new JTextField("");
    tf5 = new JTextField("");
    tf6 = new JTextField("");
    tf7 = new JTextField("");
    tf8 = new JTextField("");
    tf9 = new JTextField("");
    //reset = new JButton();

    tf1.addActionListener(this);
    tf2.addActionListener(this);
    tf3.addActionListener(this);
    tf4.addActionListener(this);
    tf5.addActionListener(this);
    tf6.addActionListener(this);
    tf7.addActionListener(this);
    tf8.addActionListener(this);
    tf9.addActionListener(this);
    ///reset.addActionListener(this);
    // p.add(tf);
    // p.add(tf2);
    p.add(tf1);
    p.add(tf2);
    p.add(tf3);
    p.add(tf4);
    p.add(tf5);
    p.add(tf6);
    p.add(tf7);
    p.add(tf8);
    p.add(tf9);
    // p.add(reset);

    c.add(p);

    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

This is my GameLogic code:

```
package Game;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class gameLogic extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6, tf7,
        tf8, tf9;
JFrame frame;
int count = 0;
String letter = "";
boolean win = false;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    gameLogic frame = new gameLogic();
}

public gameLogic() {
    super("Tic-Tac-Toe");


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method stub

    count++;

    /* Calculate Who's Turn It Is */
    if (count == 1 || count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9) {
        letter = "X";
    } else if (count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8
            || count == 10) {
        letter = "O";
    }

    if (a.getSource() == tf1) {
        tf1.setText(letter);
        tf1.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf2) {
        tf2.setText(letter);
        tf2.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf3) {
        tf3.setText(letter);
        tf3.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf4) {
        tf4.setText(letter);
        tf4.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf5) {
        tf5.setText(letter);
        tf5.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf6) {
        tf6.setText(letter);
        tf6.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf7){
        tf7.setText(letter);
        tf7.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf8) {
        tf8.setText(letter);
        tf8.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (a.getSource() == tf9) {
        tf9.setText(letter);
        tf9.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /* Determine who won */
    // horizontal wins
    if (tf1.getText() == tf2.getText()
            && tf2.getText() == tf3.getText()
            && tf1.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    } 
    else if (tf4.getText() == tf5.getText()
            && tf5.getText() == tf6.getText()
            && tf4.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }
    else if (tf7.getText() == tf8.getText()
            && tf8.getText() == tf9.getText()
            && tf7.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }

    // virticle wins
    else if (tf1.getText() == tf4.getText()
            && tf4.getText() == tf7.getText()
            && tf1.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }
    else if (tf2.getText() == tf5.getText()
            && tf5.getText() == tf8.getText()
            && tf2.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }
    else if (tf3.getText() == tf6.getText()
            && tf6.getText() == tf9.getText()
            && tf3.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }

    // diagonal wins
    else if (tf1.getText() == tf5.getText()
            && tf5.getText() == tf9.getText()
            && tf1.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }
    else if (tf3.getText() == tf5.getText()
            && tf5.getText() == tf7.getText()
            && tf3.getText() != "") {
        win = true;
    }
    else {
        win = false;
    }

    /* Show a dialog if someone wins or the game is tie */
    if (win == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " WINS!");
    }
    else if (count == 9 && win == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
    }
}
}
```

And this is what I have for my StalemateException code:

```
package exceptions;

public class StalemateException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID=123456;

public StalemateException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

}
```

I'm trying to put the StalemateException code in my GUI code so that I could have it print out that its a draw when no one has won the game but I'm not to sure how I could do this I need a bit of help as to how I could do this

Comment: Exceptions are not for game logic. Find another solution to represent the state that no one has win. :)

Comment: a stalemate is not really an unexpected event, isn't it?

Comment: I was told to make a StalemateException by my lecturer so I can't not have it I have tried a few things but nothing works I have a feeling that I'm putting it in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your own definde exception, you need to something like this:

```
public void myMethod() throws StalemateException {

    try {

        //some code

    } catch(Exception ex)
        throw new StalemateException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So the code that calling you method should look like this:

```
try {
    myMethod();
} catch(StalemateException ex)
    //handle the exception
}
```